# How to adjust nav menu based nav item name character length?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

My problem: if the name of a main nav item in my dropdown menu increases in character length, my dropdown menu breaks (see attached imageTwo). [image: messed up layout when characters are increased in nav item name]

I’m using relative units of measure (ems mostly) in hopes that would give some responsiveness to my design and adjust the layout in case of an increase in character length of the main nav items but it didn’t work.

My main menu is relatively positioned and the sub-menus are absolutely positioned. These sub-menus, rather than dropdown vertically as is standard, instead expand horizontally in parallel to the main menu above it (see attached imageOne). [image: how the menu should look]

My goal now is to figure out how to correct code so that, in case of an increase or decrease in number of characters for the nav items in the main menu a) my main nav menu can readjust it’s width appropriately and b) my sub-menu will readjust it’s positioning to appear directly beneath the main menu above it.

My thought is, I will need to use some jQuery to do this but I wondered if it was possible using only CSS.

I’ve posted my CSS below; please let me know if more information is needed.

```
#navigation {
  background: rgb(102,102,102); 
  max-height: 3.34em;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 48.5em;
  border-radius: 0;
}

#navigation .child-menu, #navigation .child-menu2 {
  display: none;
}

#navigation li.hover #admin-submenu  {
  left: -405px;
}

#navigation li.hover .child-menu {
  background: #47766c;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80em;          
  z-index: 250;
  top: 39px;
  left: -334px;
}

#navigation ul li ul li:hover .child-menu2 {
  background: #47766C;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 110px;
  z-index: 250;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#navigation ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    min-width:100%;
    height:40px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    left:0px;
    top:40px;
}
#navigation ul li ul li {
   float:left;
   height:40px;
   display:block;
   padding-left:15px;
   padding-right:15px;
}
```

You have to set the min-width of the submenus ul tag to 100% or same width as the page. Then its left:0px; Then the top is 40px or same as the parent menu height.

Comment: thanks very much for the response.  Unless I'm missing something though, your suggestion would only work if my sub-menus were the standard vertical dropdown.  Unfortunately, since my sub-menus expand horizontally (see images), these style changes revert them back to the standard vertical dropdown which I can't have.  Again, perhaps I'm not executing it properly?

Comment: fyi, I'm playing around with some of these styles you've focused on and while I've not got the solution yet, I've had some movement in the right direction.  I'll keep at it and see if I can't adjust them ftw.

Comment: I posted another image in my original question above at the very bottom of it; this is how the sub-menu looks with your changes.  It aligns nicely on the left but I'm trying to make it so that it aligns directly beneath the first nav item all the way to the left.

Comment: the submenu must be absolute and the the main ul must be relative.

Comment: Also apply some z-index to the submenu

Comment: >the submenu must be absolute and the the main ul must be relative<
my parent ul position is set to relative and the sub menu position is absolute.  Originally position relative was set on the <nav> element which is the parent of the ul but it didn't help things.

>apply some z-index to the submenu<

Z-index already there.

I did find this: http://bit.ly/Pz3V1v.  Check out the dabblet link in the answer.  This is the what I'm trying to achieve.  All your advice seems to be correct, I just can't see where mine differs to create this sub-menu mis-alignment.

Comment: Do you have link for the site?

Comment: http://dabblet.com/gist/2792978

check out the position value for both the <ul> and the ul.child: they are both absolute!  If I set the ul.child to relative, it appears to do exactly what mine is doing.  Seems counter intuitive to have both set to position: absolute;  Your thoughts?

Comment: I found the problem: there was another style being applied via velocity markup to all li's setting position: relative; once removed, the sub navs adjusted position perfectly!  Thanks for your help.